# Putting Short SHA in ENV in dockerfile, when built from Quay build trigger

Tags: docker, environment-variables, quay

I'd like to access the Short SHA (from latest GitHub commit) via an `ENV` variable inside my `Dockerfile`. But, my build is kicked off by a Quay build trigger, so it doesn't appear I can use an `ARG`. Is there any way to do this?